# Скрыть select option в safari

Tags: javascript, select, safari

Собственно нужно, чтобы в зависимости от выбора в одном select менялись значения другого (-их) select.

Сделано как в примере, но Safari не скрывает, а просто делает неактивным. В Chrome и FF работает как нужно.

Может предложите другое работающие решение...?

Так как, я понял, что Safari ни как не получиться этому научить.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var value = $(this).val();
  switch ( id ) {
   case 'select1':
      $('#select2 option').hide().prop('disabled', true);
      $('#select2 option.' + value).show().prop('disabled', false);
      $('#select2').val('default').change();
    
      $('#select3 option').hide().prop('disabled', true);
      $('#select3 option.' + value).show().prop('disabled', false);
      $('#select3').val('default').change();
    break;
  }
});
```

```css
select option[disabled] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="default" disabled selected>Выбрать</option>
  <option value="s1item1">Значение 1</option>
  <option value="s1item2">Значение 2</option>
  <option value="s1item3">Значение 3</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
  <option class="s1item1 s1item2 s1item3" value="default" disabled selected>Выбрать</option>
  <option class="s1item1 s1item2" value="s2item1">2-1</option>
  <option class="s1item1" value="s2item2">2-2</option>
  <option class="s1item1 s1item3" value="s2item3">2-3</option>
</select>
<select id="select3">
  <option class="s1item1 s1item2 s1item3" value="default" disabled selected>Выбрать</option>
  <option class="s1item1 s1item3" value="s3item1">3-1</option>
  <option class="s1item1" value="s3item2">3-2</option>
  <option class="s1item2 s1item3" value="s3item2">3-3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перешерстив просторы интернета, пришел к выводу, что на данный момент, заставить Safari работать как нужно (скрывать значения, а не делать их нектарными) не представляется возможным.